# Getting Dynamic Inventory for Sensu go from google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, sensu

I need suggestion to provide the host IP and port to `sensu-go` at runtime. Currently, we are using static inventory for our VMs which are created in `google cloud` which causes issues when those instances get deleted and new gets created.
So, I'm looking for a solution to provide the dynamic inventory to `sensu-go`. However, I could not find a way to query the google cloud in sensu-go and get the host IP(s)  by providing tag and project name.

I'm looking for a suggestion to get the host IPs for a given tag from google cloud without using `sensu-go` client in each host.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to query the google cloud and get the inventory for the tags instead of mentioning the hostnames in a file which Sensu can utilize. 
One way of doing this was installing sensu-go agent on the hosts which register theirselves to the sensu-server along with the subscription label(s) which can be utilize by the sensu-server to run an alert on the host through the sensu-client. 
But, I'm looking for an option without installing the `sensu-client`

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of IP's used by instances tagged with, say, 'sensu' you can use gcloud commands.
To get internal IP:

```
gcloud compute instances list --project=PROJECT_NAME --filter="tags.items=(SENSU)" --format="get(networkInterfaces[0].networkIP)"
```

For external IP:

```
gcloud compute instances list --project=PROJECT_NAME --filter="tags.items=(SENSU)" --format="get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)"
```